# fc.exe is displaying entire file instead of just line differences

Tags: cmd, diff, windows-10

According to fc.exe /?, it is supposed to

> Compares two files or sets of files and displays the differences between them

However, given the following two files:

```
column1,column2
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

and

```
column1,column2
a,b
c,z
e,f
```

it displays the entire files:

```
D:\downloads>fc csv1.txt csv2.txt
Comparing files csv1.txt and CSV2.TXT
***** csv1.txt
a,b
c,d
e,f
***** CSV2.TXT
a,b
c,z
e,f
*****
```

My expectation is to only see the one line that's different. Is there a way to accomplish it? I made sure using binary comparison that the files are identical in every other way:

```
D:\downloads>fc /b csv1.txt csv2.txt
Comparing files csv1.txt and CSV2.TXT
00000018: 64 7A
```

I'm on windows 10 pro.

Comment: It display one line before and one line after difference. As you can see, `column1,column2` line is not displayed.

Comment: So if I have a 4 line file, and I see all 4 lines, then there might be difference in line 1+4 or 1+3 or 2+4 or 2+3?